# Question on the definition of a norm of a linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am working through chapter 5 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, and there is something about the norm of a linear transformation I don't understand.  Rudin defines the norm of a linear transformation $\Lambda$ from a normed linear space X to a normed linear space Y as follows: $$\lvert\lvert\Lambda\rvert\rvert = \sup\{\lvert\lvert\Lambda x\rvert\rvert:x\,\epsilon\, X,\Vert x\Vert \le 1\}$$  Rudin then points out that since $\Lambda$ is linear, we have $$ (1)\,\,\, \Vert \Lambda(\alpha x)\Vert = \Vert\alpha\Lambda x\Vert=\vert\alpha\vert\Vert\Lambda x\Vert$$  So far so good.  Everything makes sense up to this point.  But then Rudin states that (1) implies that we can take the supremum over all $x\,\epsilon\,X $ such that $\Vert x \Vert=1$ rather than over all $x\,\epsilon\,X $ such that $\Vert x \Vert\le1$.  It is this part that I don't understand.  Can someone explain how this conclusion is reached from (1)?

Comment: Any vector $y$ with $|y|<1$ is of the form $\alpha x$ for some vector $x$ with $|x|=1$ and some positive constant $\alpha < 1$. So by (1), $|\Lambda y| = \alpha |\Lambda x| < |\Lambda x|$. Does this help clarify?

Comment: One has to be careful here: what if $X=\{0\}$, i.e., $X$ only contains the null vector ?

Comment: This has been covered in other Q's on this site.

Comment: Kenanski Bowspleefi, yes that does help.  I understand how it works now.  Thanks for your help!